# Optimizing operations on blobs (numpy arrays) saved in SQLite database

Tags: pandas, numpy, sqlite, optimization, sqlalchemy

I am working with a SQLite database table which has BLOB fields containing numpy arrays. So far I have returned the queries as dictionaries from SQLAclhemy and iterated over each entry, fetched the desired arrays, performed my operations, saved the output values in a pd.DataFrame and moved onto the next interation. Is there a sensible way to optimize this process?

I tried expanding the blobs in a dedicated table with an (indexed) ForeignKey to the first table, however the performance has only degraded, probably due to the delay required to locate the and fetch the correct data from the second table. I have also tried fetching all required data from the second table and performing my operations on subset of the DataFrame (using .loc[]), but it was even slower.

Comment: Are you looking to parallelize the processing of all the queries and end up with a single Dataframe? What kind of operations are you performing? Perhaps you could provide some sort of code example.

Comment: Exactly! Each entry from the first (main) table has 3 np.arrays of different length. I need to fetch them to be able to do some basic arithmetic functions on them using numpy. I have tried doing it using lambda but locating each array seems to take a lot of time since we are looking for them based on that foreignkey to the first table.